# How to adjust spacing between bars [Highcharts.js]

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have got a widget, that was made using highcharts.js and i have no control over its creation. Using .update() method i need to adjust spacings between these bars. I tried using pointPadding: 0, groupPadding: 0, but it does seem to work. Changing the height of the whole chart kinda works, but the solution is not flexible. The spacings should be of certain height (i.e 20px)
[image]

Comment: Hi @Bobby Fade, Could you refer to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/30gbyw49/ and explain the problem more precisely? Would you like to have fixed spacings between bars which changed chart's height?

Comment: @ppotaczek Yeah, i would like to have spacings of 20px between bars.

Comment: And the width of the bars should also be fixed?

Comment: @ppotaczek Yeah, it should also be 20px

Answer (score 0):

Based on the point amount, you can dynamically adapt the chart's height. For example:

```
const pointWidth = 20;
let allowChartRedraw = true;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        if (allowChartRedraw) {
          const pointsAmount = this.series[0].points.length;
          allowChartRedraw = false;
          this.setSize(
            null,
            pointsAmount * pointWidth * 2 + (this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight),
            false
          );
          allowChartRedraw = true;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    pointWidth,
    data: [...]
  }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wfxu36gd/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize